# Comparing values of different python dictionaries with different keys & structures

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

This is more of a theoretical question than anything. I have 3 dictionaries that have different structure/keys but the values may be the same. E.g.

```
dict1 = {u'd':{u'results':[{u'number':'1', u'dispURL':u'www.site.com'},
                          {u'number':u'2', u'dispURL':u'www.othersite.com'}]
              }}

dict2 = {u'result_page':{u'url':u'www.greatsite.com', u'pos':u'1'},
                        {u'url':u'www.site.com', u'pos':u'2'}}

dict3 = {u'hits':[{u'displayurl':u'www.othersite.com', u'index':u'1'},
                  {u'displayurl':u'www.site.com', u'index':u'2'}]
        }
```

Note how `dict1` has `{u'd':` before the `{u'results':`, also `dict1` and `dict3` have the different key/values enclosed in square parentheses. Also note how the keys/values layout is different in `dict1` with the `number` key coming before the `url` instead of after like in `dict2` and `dict3`, as well as the key names being different in each dictionary.

I have 3 large dictionaries like this and I need to compare them by the position of each url for scoring purposes. i.e.

```
if dict1[www.site.com index] > dict2[www.site.com index]: 
    dict1[www.site.com] score +1
```

I know the code snippet isn't correct it's just for illustration. What I want to know is what do I need to do with the dictionaries to be able to perform a comparison like this? I was thinking of taking the required data from each dictionary and putting them into 3 new dictionaries with uniform keys and structure, or even 1 new dictionary. But my program has to be computationally quite fast so I don't know how this would affect it. Any of you more experienced python programmers want to have a say on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most effective way to approach this is to convert your data into canonical {url:value} format.

For example:

```
dict1 = {data[u'dispURL']:int(data[u'number'])   for data in dict1[u'd'][u'results']}
dict2 = {data[u'url']:int(data[u'pos'])          for data in dict2[u'result_page']}
dict3 = {data[u'displayurl']:int(data[u'index']) for data in dict3[u'hits']}
```

Now they look like

```
dict1 = {u'www.othersite.com': 2, u'www.site.com': 1}
dict2 = {u'www.greatsite.com': 1, u'www.site.com': 2}
dict3 = {u'www.othersite.com': 1, u'www.site.com': 2}
```

and your comparison looks like

```
for url in dict1:
    if dict1[url] > dict2[url]:
        # do something
```

Comment: Could you please expand on that point a bit Hugh? I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: That's great thanks Hugh exactly what I was looking for. Python just makes life so much easier when you know these little tricks!